# Webservice envelope issue

Tags: web-services

I created a webservice producer from wsdl file using cxf.response is

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://esb.tiaa.org/life-insurance-correspondence-v1/types" xmlns:ns3="http://esb.tiaa.org/indianarmyshortservice">
    <soap:Body>
    <ns2:getSourcesResponse xmlns:ns2="http://channelmapwebservice.service.web.ccad/">
     <return>
        <sourceId>3</sourceId>
        <sourceName>DUMMY9</sourceName>
     </return>
```

The expected result is

```
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
  <ns1:getSourcesResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://com.ccadllc.dac.web.service.channelmapwebservice">
       <getSourcesReturn soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[644]"
 xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <getSourcesReturn xsi:type="ns2:SourceInfo"    xmlns:ns2="http://channelmapwebservice.service.web.ccad">
           <sourceId xsi:type="xsd:int">3</sourceId>
           <sourceName xsi:type="xsd:string">DUMMY9</sourceName>
        </getSourcesReturn>
```

How to obtain the exptected result

Comment: can you give use more details of your server side implementation ?

Comment: How do you expected result

Comment: I have a prodcuer and consumer.requiremnt is to re write the producer with out changing the consumer.Expected result is the response of the previous producer.Dont have the access to the code of producer and consumer.Created the clinet using the wsdl and used apache cxf to recreate the producer